# Cannot Use a Web Reference (SOAP) in Xamarin 6.1

Tags: xamarin

I made an Android App that uses a Web Reference (SOAP) that returns an array of business objects. The application worked well in old Xamarin Studio (Version 5) and old Xamarin Android (Before 6).

I have updated the Xamarin Studio and Xamarin Android for the latest version (i had a Indie Developer License) and the method that queries the Web Service (SOAP) always returns at runtime `Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)`. I Made a sample application again in Visual Studio Community 2015 consuming the same Web Reference and had the same result.

Please give me an advice. I am really stuck!.

This is the error from VS2015:

```
{System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000cb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1313 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0019b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:195 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:882 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00057] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:900 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00069] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:353 }
```

Comment: Are you using emulator? Is wifi on in your emulator. This error occurs when you are not able to connect to your webservice.

Comment: I am using a tablet attached to an usb port and the emulator. With Xamarin Studio 5.10.3 and Xamarin Android 6.0.2.1 Indie Edition (Before applying the updates) works the application without problems and as expected to work.

Comment: This is the About Data: 

Version 5.10.3 (build 27)
Runtime:
 Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
 GTK+ 2.24.23 (MS-Windows theme)
 GTK# 2.12.30
=== Xamarin.Android ===
Version: 6.0.2.1 (Indie Edition)
SDK Tools Version: 24.3.4
SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.0.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.1

java version "1.6.0_39"

=== Operating System ===
Windows 10.0.10586.0 (64-bit)